# Unable to deploy container images on Google Compute Engine

Tags: laravel, docker, google-compute-engine, laravel-6, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to deploy my container image on Compute Engine using `cloudbuild.yaml` but getting error. Below is my `cloudbuild.yaml` file content:

```
# gis-account-manager -> Project ID on GCP
steps:
# Build the Docker image.
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/gis-account-manager/ams', '-f', 'Dockerfile', '.']
  
# Push it to GCR.
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/gis-account-manager/ams']

# Deploy to Prod env (THIS STEP IS FAILING)
 - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: [ 'compute', 'instances', 'update-container', 'instance-2-production' , '--container-image', 'gcr.io/gis-account-manager/ams:latest']
  
# Set the Docker image in Cloud Build
images: ['gcr.io/gis-account-manager/ams']

# Build timeout
timeout: '3600s'
```

**Error:**

> Starting Step #2
>
> Step #2: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
>
> Step #2: ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.update-container) Underspecified resource [instance-2-production]. Specify the [--zone] flag.

If I run the same command from Cloud SDK Sheel it works as expected.

PS: I've also tried by providing ZONE Flag.

Comment: **don't upload** error's image. **write** your error message in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue by authenticating via service account (First need to **generate keys for Compute Engine Service Account**).

Updated `cloudbuild.yaml` file:

```
# Deploy to GOOGLE COMPUTE ENGINE Prod env
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: [ 'auth', 'activate-service-account', '123456789-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com', '--key-file=PATH_TO_FILE', '--project=${_PROJECT_ID}']
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: ['compute', 'instances', 'update-container', '${_VM_INSTANCE}' , '--container-image=gcr.io/${_PROJECT_ID}/ams:latest', '--zone=us-central1-a']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your zone in gcloud compute command:

```
# Deploy to Prod env (THIS STEP IS FAILING)
 - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: [ 'config', 'set', 'compute/zone', 'us-central1-a']
 - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: [ 'compute', 'instances', 'update-container', 'instance-2-production' , '--container-image', 'gcr.io/gis-account-manager/ams:latest']
```

You need to to change asia-east1 by [zone from this list](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/). And since you are updating the container then the zone may be already specified.

You can write the command: `gcloud compute zones list` to list all available zones

Comment: Is it the same error? and are you sure that this is the correct zone? and if so, please update your question with new added code and errors.

Comment: Step #2: Already have an image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud

Step #2: ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.update-container) HTTPError 403: Required 'compute.instances.get' permission for 'projects/gis-account-manager/zones/us-central1-a/instances/instance-2-production'

I do have the right permissions. If I don't have permissions then it shouldn't be working from the shell.

Comment: Yes, the zone(us-central1-a) is correct as a compute instance is already exists.
Whenever I try to update it from the shell, it works flawlessly.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Instead of setting the zone in the same command. You configure it in a preceding command.

Comment: I've tried as you recommended first config for zone, then deploy command.

But still getting same error "Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.update-container) HTTPError 403: Required 'compute.instances.get' permission for 'projects/gis-account-manager/zones/us-central1-a/instances/instance-2-production'"

Comment: I believe that the error message `HTTPError 403: Required 'compute.instances.get' permission for 'projects/gis-account-manager/zones/us-central1-a/instances/instance-2-production` is very clear. You will need to grant permission access in your specified project to use `compute.instances.get` and be able to build up your step. Check out this link [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/granting-access-to-resources). As for the `--zone`, you will most likely need to specify the zone, as well. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Yep, the message is clear. But if I update the container via cloud SDK shell it works. This is driving me crazy as I'm using the same account on both places and I do have access to compute.instances.get.

Answer (score 0):

> **Cloud Build does not have enough permissions to execute the operation, hence you are receiving an error when operating on Cloud Build, but not when executing the same operation in `gcloud` command-line tool, which works differently.**

I granted these Cloud Build Service Account and Cloud Build Service Agent with the Compute Admin role:

- [REDACTED]@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`
- service-[REDACTED]@gcp-sa-cloudbuild.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

My `cloudbuild.yaml` looks identical to what you should have now:

```
    steps:
    - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
      args: [ 'config', 'set', 'compute/zone', 'YOUR_ZONE']
    - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
      args: [ 'compute', 'instances', 'update-container', '[YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME]' , '--container-image', 'gcr.io/gis-account-manager/ams:latest']
```

where `[YOUR_ZONE]` is your configured zone and `[YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME]` is the name of your instance.

I would recommend that you read on this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/set-service-account-permissions) for more information about Cloud Build service accounts permissions.